# Changing The Log Out Sound

Tags: logout

I would like to change the log out sound in Ubuntu 12.04. Is there a command for the terminal so this script can be edited?

Answer (score 1):

Just change the file:

/usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/desktop-logout.ogg

For other of your choice. Keep the same name and make sure it's a .ogg file

Comment: Thx, but the file needs to be in "root" to put a file into the folder, I'm not sure how to do this. Also my log off sound is actually the drums and this comes from the system ready .ogg file, shared?

Comment: Ok great thank you, I have my sound file changed to "root" now using the "sudo nautilus" command and is now working.